# read xml and assign attributes to variables in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net-2010

I have a xml file

```
<config>
   <email Host="201.175.0.0" From="address@gmail.com" Pass="xxx" Name="NameT"/>
   <combo/>
   <list sex="female"/>
</config>
```

How can I assign the value of the attributes to variables in vb.net?

I was doing

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("Test.xml")
Dim Host = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.ItemOf("Host").InnerText
Dim From = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.ItemOf("From").InnerText
Dim Pass = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.ItemOf("Pass").InnerText
Dim Name = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.ItemOf("Name").InnerText
```

Is this correct, what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("Test.xml")
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Dim nodeEmail As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/email")
Dim Host As String = nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Host").InnerText
Dim From As String = nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("From").InnerText
Dim Pass As String = nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Pass").InnerText
Dim Name As String = nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Name").InnerText
```

You might also want to consider using an associative array (Dictionary in VB) to store those attributes, rather than using a bunch of variables.

In that case, it would look like this:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("Test.xml")
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Dim nodeEmail As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/email")
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("Host", nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Host").InnerText)
dictionary.Add("From", nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("From").InnerText)
dictionary.Add("Pass", nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Pass").InnerText)
dictionary.Add("name", nodeEmail.Attributes.ItemOf("Name").InnerText)
```

Comment: thats a very good idea, do you have an example to use Dictionary?