# How to create variables in vb.net with variable names being element name which are read from an xml file

Tags: .net, xml, database, vb.net

I am working on a project where in, the database is stored into an XML file. I need to created a VB.Net project where we read the contents of this xml file and use the data further.

Specifically I need to read the elements of xml file and then create variables of the type string, with variable name being the name of the element read from xml file.

Eg:

XML file :

```
<NameOfFruit>Apple</NameOfFruit>
<ScientificName>Malus domestica</ScientificName>
```

Now in my vb.net code I want to create variables with name "**NameOfFruit**" and "**ScientificName**".
I read the contents of xml file using - [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class of vb.net.

Each time my program reads the element name from xml file, I want to create a variable with name being that if element name.

My database is a huge file and I am new to vb.net. Request for guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a code generator to build some code every once in a while? Or are you looking to have variables generated at run-time, dynamicaly, relative to the XML file... if so.. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse an XML file and to create an auto-generated class in VB.net then you should do this using the xsd.exe tool which comes as part of the Dev tools in Visual Studio.

You will need to open the Dev Command Prompt to run the tool. 
[Open Command Prompt from inside Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx#visualstudio)

The default location for Command Prompt for VS 2013 is [here](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMicrosoft%20Visual%20Studio%2012.0%5CCommon7%5CTools%5CShortcuts%5CDeveloper%20Command%20Prompt%20for%20VS2013.lnk), but this could change according to installation location.

In the Command Prompt run the following commands:

> xsd 'yourfilename'.xml /classes /language:vb

Example: 
[image]
This will auto-generate the XML Scheme File 'yourfilename'.xsd in the directory folder

and next run this:

> xsd 'yourfilename'.xsd /classes /language:vb

Example: 
[image]
This will auto-generate a VB class from the XSD file which will be contained in a VB file called 'yourfilename'.vb.

Then you can simply add the VB file with your class to your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion.

Comment: @SKO if this was helpful for you, I'd appreciate it if you +1 the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

[read xml and assign attributes to variables in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733654/read-xml-and-assign-attributes-to-variables-in-vb-net)

The above link is helpful on assigning attributes to variables

Maybe something like the below could work. This is assigning the xml element's value to a generic list

```
Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(file)
Dim xml As XElement = xmlDoc.Root
Dim food As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml.Elements
Dim NameOfFruit As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Index As Integer = 0 To (food.Count - 1)
    NameOfFruit.Add(food.ElementAt(Index).Element("NameOfFruit").Value)
Next
```

Comment: Hi Cal-cium, thank you for your suggestions, it helped me explore more related to vb.net but the thing that I was looking for cant be achieved. I think may be it not possible to create variable dynamically with name that are fetched from a file.

Comment: Why would you want to create a variable with a name fetched from a file? surely you would want to read in the data from the xml file into a variable?

Comment: In my code name of element and text contained into the element is a part of data. I need to use both the information that I obtain from the file.